# Convert a simple JSON object to a properties file

Tags: bash, sh, jq

I have a simple JSON object and would like to convert it into a properties file in bash.

Input:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "abc": "def ghi"
}
```

expected output:

```
foo="bar"
abc="def ghi"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `to_entries` for that:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[]|"\(.key)=\"\(.value)\""' input.json
```

Btw, in Java properties files you don't need to quote the value:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[]|"\(.key)=\(.value)"' input.json
```

Comment: Use `@sh` instead of quoting the value yourself; this is necessary to ensure something like `{"key": "\"value\""}` gets correctly quoted. (`'... | "\(.key)=\(.value | @sh)"'`).

Comment: @chepner The OP wants to write a properties file, which makes me think of Java. These files follow different syntax rules than the shell. Actually the double quotes aren't necessary at all. Well, the op seems to expect them.

Comment: If the double quotes are indeed unnecessary, I would leave them out. If value itself contains quotes, the result isn't going to be correct.

Comment: I'm not a Java expert, probably they are just superfluous. I can ad it as an alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work for nested structures (like in a 
Spring Boot `application.yml`)

Comment: @Matthias I recommend to open a question if your use case is different from this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the usage of `to_entries' and `@sh' filter will work only for *simple* JSON objects (As stated in the question...). In my case (nested json) seems I'll use npm's package "json-to-properties"

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nested structure you can define a file, for example `to-properties.jq`:

```
def val_at($path; $json):
  $json | getpath($path)
;

. as $json
  | [paths(type != "object")]
  | map("\(join("."))=\(val_at(.; $json))")
  | join("\n")
```

You can then invoke `jq -r -f to-properties.jq file.json` which would output something like:

```
bar.baz=abc
foo.bar=123
foo.bar.baz=xyz
```