# JSON to plain text using jq

Tags: json, jq

Let's say i got the following json response:

```
{
  "author": "tomek",
  "title": "helloworld",
  "test": "sampletextonetwothree"
}
```

Is it possible to display something like this: (using jq)

```
author=tomek
title=helloworld
test=sampletextonetwothree
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a simple JSON object to a properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356536/convert-a-simple-json-object-to-a-properties-file)

Comment: See the linked answer `jq -r 'to_entries[]|"\(.key)=\"\(.value)\""' input.json`

Comment: Yes, it's perfect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sh
jq 'to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value)"'
```

should do it

Comment: Nice! Somehow I tried to do this and was getting errors. I must have missed a parenthesis escape somewhere.

Comment: Actually just noticed you wanted it without quotes, so you probably prefer @Philippe's answer

Comment: You can remove the quotes by adding the -r flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to join the values is to use [string concatenation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Addition:+):

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | .key + "=" + .value'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way, but this works:

```
cat response.json | jq -r 'to_entries| map([.key, .value]) | map([join("=")]) | flatten | .[]'
```

or

```
cat response.json | jq -r 'to_entries | map([.key, .value]) | .[] | join("=")'
```

Comment: you're missing a closing single-quote

Comment: THanks @Philippe